# Connection on pullback principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

For a Lie group $G$, let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a smooth manifold $M$. Let $\omega: TE \rightarrow Lie(G)$ be a connection 1-form on $E$. Let $f:N \rightarrow M$ be smooth map. We know that there is a natural principal $G$-bundle structure on the pullback bundle $f^{*}E \rightarrow N$, induced from the principal $G$- bundle $\pi:E \rightarrow M$.

**My question is the following:**

Is there a natural way to define a connection 1-form on the pullback G-bundle $f^{*}E$ for any smooth map $f:N \rightarrow M$, induced from $\omega$? If not, then under what condition on $f:N \rightarrow M$, we can naturally define a connection 1-form on $f^{*}E$, induced from $\omega$?

**Edit:**[**This question is closed**] I apologise deeply for asking the question in this forum without providing any context. This question came up to me in the context of constructing a stack of principal $G$-bundles with connections over smooth manifolds. For the construction of the associated pseudofunctor, I had to ensure a canonical connection form on the pullback principal bundle induced from a connection form on the original principal bundle.

I will try my best to not repeat these kind of mistakes while asking questions in the forum in future.

Comment: Yes, [see item 4 on page 35](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/principal.pdf).

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pullback bundle $f^*E$ satisfies the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
f^*E @>{F}>> E\\
@V{\pi}VV @VV{\pi}V\\
N @>{f}>> M
\end{CD}
So we can pull the form $\omega\in \Omega^1(E,\mathrm{Lie}(G))$ back to a form on $F^*\omega\in \Omega^1(f^*E,\mathrm{Lie}(G))$ defined by $F^*\omega(v)=\omega(T_p F v)$ for $v\in T_pf^*E$. Since the $G$ action on $f^*E$ comes from the $G$ action on $E$, this form will define a connection form.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Comment: This is correct. But I just want to note a subtlety that occurs when $f$ is not a diffeomorphism. Consider the case when $f$ is constant. Since the pullback of the connection 1-form vanishes, it appears that the covariant derivative of any section vanishes. But of course this cannot be.

Comment: @Deane
 If $f$ is constant wouldn't $f^*E$ be the trivial $\pi^{-1}(f(n))$ bundle over $N$ for any $n\in N$. Under this identification $F: N\times \pi^{-1}(f(n))\to E$ is $\mathrm{pr}_2\circ \iota_{f(n)}$ where $\mathrm{pr}_2$ is the projection onto the second factor and $\iota_{f(n)}$ is the inclusion of $\pi^{-1}(f(n))$ into $E$. This means that $T_pF\neq 0$ for all $p\in N$ and $F^*\omega$ is nonzero.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter, yes that's correct.